# Executing card and deck classes in python

Tags: python, class, execution

```
class Card:
RANKS = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    self.suit = suit
    self.rank = rank

def get_name(self):
    return Card.RANKS[self.rank - 1] + ' of ' + self.suit

def equals(self, other_card):
    if self.rank == self.other_card:
        return True
    elif self.rank != self.other_card:
        return False 

def greater_than(self, other_card):
    if self.rank > self.other_card:
        return True
    elif self.rank < self.other_card:
        return False

def less_than(self, other_card):
    if self.rank < self.other_card:
        return True
    elif self.rank > self.other_card:
        return False 


class Deck:
def __init__(self):
    self.available_cards = []
    self.dealt_cards = []
    for suit in ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs']:
        for rank in range(1, 14):
            self.available_cards.append(Card(rank, suit))

def shuffle(self):
    """
    Shuffles the cards in the deck.
    """
    import random
    return random.shuffle(self.available_cards)

def deal_card(self):
    self.available_cards.add(Card)
    self.available_cards.remove(Card)
    self.dealt_cards.append(Card)

def get_size(self):
    return len[self.available_cards]

c = Card()
print(c.available_cards)

d = Deck()
d.shuffle()
print(d.dealt_cards)
```

So what I've done here is that I've made a Card class and a Deck class, but I'm having trouble executing it. I'm trying to test the two classes by shuffling it, and using it to deal some cards. But when I try to run it won't work. What should I do?

Comment: what you should do is post the error message since it is unlikely anyone here is clairvoyant.  Though if I had to venture a guess, you should probably check your indents since they matter in Python.

Comment: "it won't work". Maybe share those details via an [edit]? Please see [ask].

Comment: ["it won't work".](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)...

Comment: At first glance I see: get_name is called __str__, equals is called __eq__, greater_than is called __gt__ and less_than is called __lt__ in python. And a Card object has no method available_cards.

Comment: There is no `self.other_card` in those comparing functions. it should just be `other_card` And probably should access some member of that card. Also `rank` is being compared as Strings....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is surely:

```
c = Card()
print(c.available_cards)
```

Because 1) does the constructor of the `Card` class take 2 arguments (`rank` and `suit` and 2) does the Cards class not have `available_cards`, so trying to acces `c.available_cards` will not work

So not knowing what you intended with those two lines I omitted them from further debugging.

Now you are doing:

```
d = Deck()
```

okay, that doesn't need any argument and creates a new deck with all the cards in a standard 52 deck and initializes `dealt_cards` to `[]`.

Now you immediatly print

```
print(d.dealt_cards)
```

which will of course result in an empty list:

```
print(d.dealt_cards)
>>>[]
```

What you might have intended is probably to deal some cards first and then print the result:

```
for i in range(4):
    d.deal_card()
print(d.dealt_cards)
```

This however results in an error message since your `deal_card` is not correct. You don't want to add anything to the `available_cards`, but remove one item from it and add it to your `dealt_cards` like so:

```
def deal_card(self):
    # self.available_cards.add(Card)
    # self.available_cards.remove(Card)
    self.dealt_cards.append(self.available_cards.pop())
```

Now you will notice that `print(d.dealt_cards)` does not output the cards in the list in a "pretty" way, instead you might see something like this:

```
[<__main__.Card object at 0x00000285E8C0A978>, <__main__.Card object at 0x00000285E8C0AA58>, <__main__.Card object at 0x00000285E8C0A4E0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x00000285E8BFCF28>]
```

That is because you havn't taught your script how to print a card. For this we add a method to the Cards class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.get_name()
```

whenever printing an instance of the cards class now, we will get the desired output.

Final code:

```
class Card:
    

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    def get_name(self):
        return Card.ranks[self.rank - 1] + ' of ' + self.suit

    def equals(self, other_card):
        if self.rank == other_card.rank:
            return True
        elif self.rank != other_card.rank:
            return False

    def greater_than(self, other_card):
        if self.rank > other_card.rank:
            return True
        elif self.rank < other_card.rank:
            return False

    def less_than(self, other_card):
        if self.rank < other_card.rank:
            return True
        elif self.rank > other_card.rank:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.get_name()


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.available_cards = []
        self.dealt_cards = []
        for suit in ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs']:
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                self.available_cards.append(Card(rank, suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        """
        Shuffles the cards in the deck.
        """
        import random
        return random.shuffle(self.available_cards)

    def deal_card(self):
        # self.available_cards.add(Card)
        # self.available_cards.remove(Card)
        self.dealt_cards.append(self.available_cards.pop())

    def get_size(self):
        return len(self.available_cards)

# c = Card()
# print(c.available_cards)

d = Deck()
d.shuffle()
for i in range(4):
    d.deal_card()
print(d.dealt_cards)
>>>[6 of Spades, Jack of Hearts, 4 of Spades, Queen of Spades]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept (click in the checkmark on the left of the answer) the answer if you feel like it resolved your issue

Comment: self.ranks is missing 10
get_size(self) len method needs parenthesis len(self.available_cards)